# Unable query database with null field, getting zero results

Tags: php, mysql, null

I'm unable to query database with null field. Tried several iteration with google search with no success and hoping someone here can help me.

I have 2 tables:

```
tableOne                                  tableTwo
Index   FirstName   userID  colorID        index   colors
1     Bob               3       2             1      green
2     mike              4       3             2      blue
3     Jack              8        NULL         3      yellow
4     Jill              9        4            4      pink
5     Smith             7        2
6     Brown             2        2
```

my php/mysql script:

```
$variableID = 8;
try{ $STH = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT  tableOne.FirstName,                                                                                                                                 
                                     tableTow.colors,                                                        
            FROM  tableOne, tableTwo 

            WHERE tableOne.userID = $variableID and                  
                   tableOne.userID = tableTwo.index  ");

            $STH->execute();
            $incidentDetails = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch(PDOException $e) { echo  $e->getMessage(); }
```

Problem area:  tableOne.userID = tableTwo.index

Looking for desired outcome:

**if $variableID = 8 and tableOne.ColorID == NULL
out come should be Jack**

**if  $variableID = 8 and tableOne.ColorID == 3 (tableOne.colorID right now is NULL but it also could be 3)
looking for desired out come
Jack and Yellow**.

so what im looking for is a way to evaluate if its a NULL dont bother with the color else query the color.

any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need `' '` around your $variableID in your query

```
...WHERE tableOne.userID = $variableID and...
```

should be

```
...WHERE tableOne.userID = '$variableID' and...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply back but thats not problem as the script i copy pasted works unless the tableOne.userID is null